# multiple parameter passing by ajax in CI controller not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter

When i am passing two parameter in ajax call to CI controller, values are displaying null in live server.but if i send one parameter it works fine.Everything works fine in local server.

Ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#searchoption").keyup(function ()
{

var searchdata = $(this).val();
//alert(searchdata);
$.ajax({
url: BASE_URL + 'somajsebadmin/somajsebadmin_dashboard/search_muktijuddha_vatha_information',
type: 'POST',
 data: 'searchvalue=' + searchdata + '&table_name=' + 'muktijuddha_vatha_application',
beforeSend: function() {
// setting a timeout
$('#loader').show();
},
success: function (data) {
$('#loader').hide();
$("#searchdata").html(data);
}
});

});
});
</script>
```

My controller method code

```
public function search_muktijuddha_vatha_information() {

//     header('Content-Type: application/json');


if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

$searchvalue = $this->input->post('searchvalue');
$tableName = $this->input->post('table_name');

//  $tableName = 'muktijuddha_vatha_application';

var_dump($searchvalue,$tableName);
}
}
```

output

null null

my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with object in AJAX:

```
data: { searchvalue: searchdata, table_name: 'muktijuddha_vatha_application' },
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug your code, I would start with ajax, you have your var_dump in jquery exported as

```
$("#searchdata").html(data);
```

I always use console.log(data), so you don't have problems with css or html that is not putting your var_dump data out. so try this:

```
console.log(data);
```

Second thing open your inspect element on chrome or on FF firebug, to see if there is POST made it and to what URL, and what data has been posted.

So then you checked if ajax is posting to url, then if url exists and what is respond of URL and then if respond is displayed from PHP and then see if console.log (or like you did $("#searchdata").html(data);) did export your var_dump.

and to post multi data try  to post like this:

```
data: { code: code, userid: userid }
```

or in your case like this:

```
 data {searchvalue: searchdata, table_name:'muktijuddha_vatha_application' }
```

Comment: I also use firebug and inspect element in chrome for debugging.It is passed the actual value as post parameter but when i vur_dump at CI result is null,null. I said that if i sent one parameter it works fine problem on multiple parameter.also multiple parameter works fine in localhost

Comment: so can you tell me what do you see at inspect element under network, what is passed to CI? what POST is passed to php url?

Comment: it should pass searchdata and muktijuddha_vatha_application and then in CI you can say: var_dump($_POST); to see all posted values

Comment: When you see var_dump($_POST), then you can go and do codeigniter way of getting the post values like you did: $searchvalue = $this->input->post('searchvalue');
$tableName = $this->input->post('table_name');

Comment: from your code the second value is: table_name=' + 'muktijuddha_vatha_application' and it is not variable value 'muktijuddha_vatha_application' it will be always: muktijuddha_vatha_application in var_dump, but have a good look if value is posted to CI? if not try to change code to object as post from ajax like mentioned above

Comment: bro, at firebug  var_dump($_POST) display array(0){} and response post display like what i posted

Comment: it is all about multiple parameter if i pass one parameter it works but add another parameter not worked@Srle Srle